# boost::multi_index and std::map find() and erase()

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

It is possible wrap the `boost::multi_index` `find()` and `erase()` methods for obtain similiar `std::map` `find()` and `erase()` methods?

[*from the comments:*] I have this method:

```
typename container1::const_iterator find(const K& key) const
{
  //typedef typename nth_index<container1,0>::type it; c.get<1>().find(key);
  return (???);
}
```

What should I write in my return statement??

Comment: Please post an example (pseudo-code is OK) of what you want to do; I can't understand from your verbal description what your problem is.

Comment: @kerrekSB: I have this method:
 'typename container1::const_iterator find(const K& key) const
 {
   //typedef typename nth_index<container1,0>::type it;
   c.get<1>().find(key);
   return (???);
 }'
 What should I write in my return statement??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to return an index-0 iterator whereas the lookup is done with index 1, right? Use [iterator projection](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#projection):

```
template<typename Container, typename Key>
typename Container::const_iterator find(const Container& c, const Key& key)
{
  return c.project<0>(c.get<1>().find(key));
}
```